# A conflict between caption & longtable packages raises the "overfull \hbox" warning!

Tags: errors, captions, longtable, warnings

**Problem:** Overfull `\hbox (416.83289pt too wide) detected` .. warning message with `longtable`, at the `\caption{}` line.

**Possible explanation (IMHO) :** The `caption package` clashes with the `\caption{}` definition set by the `longtable package`; which is nothing but --`\multicolumn{\LT@cols}{c}{<a \parbox of width \LTcapwidth , with the table's caption>}` inside a box of `width 0pt`, so that it never affects the column widths (ref.- `longtable documentation`). If this turns out to be true (according to experts), then it is surprising, because according to both package documentations, these packages are supposed to be compatible.

**My Workaround** (which is unacceptable to me) **:** Either remove the entire `\caption{}` line or remove the `caption package` along with the corresponding `\captionsetup{}` configuration. *It is unacceptable because, in my thesis there are several other figures, tables, listings, etc. for which the* `caption package` *& the* `\captionsetup{}` *configuration has worked beautifully!*

**MWE's :** 1. with `caption package` & 2. without `caption package`

*Note: I've used* `showframe` *&* `\documentclass[draft]{<class>}` *to point out the problematic line/s in the output.*

**MWE 1 :** with `caption package` :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.5in,left=1.5in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption} % This is throwing a "400+ pt overfull hbox error" for longtables!
\usepackage{lipsum}

% A group of packages required for tables 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{periodQuad}{. \quad}  % DIY customisation of labelsep  
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{tabulab}{\textbullet\quad #1 #2}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{periodQuad}[labelsep=period]{labelsep=periodQuad}

\captionsetup{%
        font={sf,up}, 
        labelfont={bf},
        singlelinecheck=true,
        justification=centerfirst,
        labelformat=tabulab,
        labelsep=periodQuad, 
        position=bottom
        }%

\providecommand{\negsci}[1]{\ensuremath{\hspace*{0.5pt}\text{\sc{e}\hspace*{0.5pt}{-}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[9]
\vspace*{-2em}

{                           % Begin group --- % To keep the effect local!
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\LTpost{-14ex}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.6}
%\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc@{}}
\caption[Parameter Values for the model]{Parameter Values for the model\label{tab:mod_pars}}\medskip\\
% Gives (./longtableMWE.tex Overfull \hbox (416.83289pt too wide) detected .. ERROR!  
\midrule
Equation & Parameter & Value & Units & Reference \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\midrule
\endhead
\addlinespace[4pt]\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textcolor{gray}{\footnotesize(\textit{Continued on next page $\ldots$})}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
16 & Adenine Total & 4.81 & mM & 2-6, \& 23-25 \\
31, 36 & Calcium ions & {6.0}\negsci{03}{} & mM & 56, 23, 55, 12 \\
34 & Carbon dioxide & 1.63 & mM & 9, 11, 4, 8 \\
13, 17, 3, 6 & CoA Total & 2.7 & mM & 5, 11 \\
20 & Bicarbonate & 21.2 & mM & 7, 23, 42, 63 \\
52, 16, 23 & Cytosolic Malate & 0.47 & mM & \textemdash \\
\midrule\addlinespace[5em]
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
}                           % End group --- % To keep the effect local! 

\lipsum[8]
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

**Output for MWE 1 :** with `caption package` :

[image]

**MWE 2 :** without `caption package` :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.5in,left=1.5in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{caption} % This is throwing a "400+ pt overfull hbox error" for longtables!
\usepackage{lipsum}

% A group of packages required for tables 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

% For formatting the numbers in scientific format
\providecommand{\negsci}[1]{\ensuremath{\hspace*{0.5pt}\text{\sc{e}\hspace*{0.5pt}{-}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[9]
\vspace*{-1em}

{                           % Begin group --- % To keep the effect local!
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\LTpost{-14ex}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.6}
%\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc@{}}
\caption[Parameter Values for the model]{Parameter Values for the model\label{tab:mod_pars}}\\
% Gives (./longtableMWE.tex Overfull \hbox (416.83289pt too wide) detected .. ERROR!
\midrule
Equation & Parameter & Value & Units & Reference \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\midrule
\endhead
\addlinespace[4pt]\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textcolor{gray}{\footnotesize(\textit{Continued on next page $\ldots$})}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
16 & Adenine Total & 4.81 & mM & 2-6, \& 23-25 \\
31, 36 & Calcium ions & {6.0}\negsci{03}{} & mM & 56, 23, 55, 12 \\
34 & Carbon dioxide & 1.63 & mM & 9, 11, 4, 8 \\
13, 17, 3, 6 & CoA Total & 2.7 & mM & 5, 11 \\
20 & Bicarbonate & 21.2 & mM & 7, 23, 42, 63 \\
52, 16, 23 & Cytosolic Malate & 0.47 & mM & \textemdash \\
\midrule\addlinespace[5em]
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
}                           % End group --- % To keep the effect local! 

\lipsum[8]
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

**Output for MWE 2 :** without `caption package` :

[image]

Therefore, between these 2 outputs, we can clearly see where the `overfull \hbox error` occurs and how it disappears when the `caption package` is removed. I wish to use both the `longtable` as well as the `caption` packages in my thesis and therefore this workaround is useless for me. Could anyone please help me troubleshoot this error, without removing `caption package`? Also, the `overfull \hbox` error is large enough (almost `400+ pt`!) to not be overlooked! Any help/ suggestions/ pointers will be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That is a seriously impressive first post on here. Show-off. :)

Comment: Thank you @henry! .. no show-off, I just wanted to attract @david's attention to it and that's why made it as proper as possible according to my limited knowledge. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that `caption` package version is not expecting `\LTleft` to be set to 0pt.

setting

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt plus \textwidth}
\setlength\LTright{0pt plus \textwidth}
```

centres the caption without affecting the table (as the fill glue in extracolsep
cancels out this finite stretch)

You should also remove the `center` environment which does not affect the alignment but just adds spurious vertical space (which is probably why you set `\LTpost` negative)

Comment: Thank you @david! I changed my code according to your suggestions and also removed the `center` environment and presto! All of that overfull-ness just disappeared! Thanks once again, you saved me from a lot of head scratching! :)